# For which $t \in \mathbb{R}$ is the subset $W \subseteq \mathbb R^4$ a linear subspace?

Tags: vector-spaces

> Determine parameter $t \in \mathbb{R}$ so that the set $W = \{ (x_{1},...,x_{4}) \colon 3x_{1} - 2x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} - t (x_{1}^{2} + x_{4}^{2}) = 0 \} $ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R} ^{4}$.

It is obvious that $W \subseteq \mathbb{R} ^{4}$ is a linear subspace for $ t = 0$. But, when I try to find such $t \neq 0$ I get stuck ( it seems to me that $ t = 0$ is the only solution but I can not think of any counterexample for other $t \in \mathbb{R}$). Any hint helps!

Comment: What does $W < \mathbb R^4$ means?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net that means that $W$ is subspace of vector space $\mathbb{R} ^{4}$.

Comment: Do you mean a linear subspace? $W$ is always included in $\mathbb R^4$!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net yes, I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, $W$ is a linear subspace for $t = 0$.

It is not a linear subspace for $t \neq 0$. Notice that $(1, 2, 2t, 1) \in W$. If $W$ was a linear subspace, $2 \cdot (1, 2, 2t, 1) = (2, 4, 4t, 2)$ would belong to $W$. But

$$3 \cdot 2 -2 \cdot 4 + 4t +2 - 8t = -4t \neq 0.$$